# how to swap rows in csv file with python?

Tags: python, database, csv

I have 11k csv files where I have only two rows they look like this

```
---------------------------
             | A0.31       |
---------------------------
some data    |             |
---------------------------
```

and I want them in one only row

```
---------------------------
some data    | A0.31       |
---------------------------
```

I have this code but it just replaces the values not putting them in one row

```
import csv, os

with open('path/to/filename') as inf, open('path/to/filename_temp', 'w') as outf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf)
    writer = csv.writer(outf)
    for line in reader:
        if line[1] == '0':
           ...
        ... # as above

os.remove('path/to/filename')
os.rename('path/to/filename_temp', 'path/to/filename')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
#!python
value=""
data=""
with open("test.csv","r") as inF, open("out.csv","w") as outF:
    lines= inF.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if "-" in line:
            continue
        if line.isspace():
            continue
        fields=line.split("|")
        if not fields[1].isspace():
            value=fields[1]
        elif not fields[0].isspace():
            data=fields[0]
        else:
            continue
    outF.write("-------------------------------------\n")
    outF.write(data +"|" + value+ "|" +"\n")
    outF.write("-------------------------------------\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You indicate your files are CSV, so I'm going to assume your files are actually in CSV format, i.e. as follows:

```
,'A0.31'
'some data',
```

If your files are really that short, I would simply load both rows in the file, and immediately after that write the combined result to the same file:

```
import csv

data = []
with open('path/to/filename') as inf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf)
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)

with open('path/to/filename', 'w') as outf:
    writer = csv.writer(outf)
    writer.writerow([data[1][0], data[0][1]])
```

Comment: ,syn,A01.0 Брюшной тиф
0,"Тиф брюшной, Паратиф, Тиф, Паратифозная лихорадка",num


okay this is my input csv

this what I get after your code


0,